# 'Permission denied' error when counting files

Tags: vbscript, count, directory

I'm trying to count (recursivly) the number of files in a folder using VBS.

I have derived the following function but whenever I run it I get an error -

> 800A0046 - Permission denied

This happens on all of the folders I wish to know the file count of, with all folders either being local or on a mapped drive to which I have full access.

I have passed the folder paths both with and without a trailing slash and the error still occurs.

Can anybody tell me how I can fix this problem?

```
Function CountFiles(ByVal folder)

    Dim parentFolder
    Dim subFolder
    Dim count

    '** Grab an instance of the current parent folder *'
    Set parentFolder = FSO.GetFolder(folder)

    '** Count the files in the parent folder *'
    count = parentFolder.Files.Count

    '** Count all files in each subfolder - recursion point *'
    For Each subFolder In parentFolder.SubFolders
        count = count + CountFiles(subFolder.Path)
    Next

    '** Return a count of the files *'
    CountFiles = count

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

By removing the dangerous fat from David's code (lavishly introducing variables (like IntCount), spurious back (folder object) and forth (folder.Path)) you get a clean function:

```
Option Explicit

Const csFolder = ".\"

Dim goFS : Set goFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Function CountFiles(oFolder)
    CountFiles = oFolder.Files.Count
    Dim oSubFolder
    For Each oSubFolder In oFolder.SubFolders
        CountFiles = CountFiles + CountFiles(oSubFolder)
    Next
End Function

WScript.Echo "Files in", csFolder, CountFiles(goFS.GetFolder(csFolder))
```

This can be tested (e.g. on "\"):

```
cscript 30263200.vbs
Files in .\ 146
```

and checked vs the Properties of the folder shown by the Explorer (trust me, the 146 files are correct).

If you get a "Permission denied" for some other folder, then there is at least one folder in the tree you don't have permission to access. If **all**
of the starting folders you are interested in cause this error, you have no permissions for **any** of them.

As there are reasons for the granting of permissions, this probably is a good thing.

Consider to shell out to `dir /s /b`, which would give you a list of all the folders/files you are entitled to know about without breaking if there are any forbidden ones.

Comment: Unfortunately this is still causing me problems.  Even using a copy and paste of your code (with the exception of the value of `csFolder`, whcih is set to the **My Documents** folder) I get the 'Permission denied' error.  Curiously though, trial and error shows that running the function against any folder withing My Documents works.  I was using ownCloud to sync My Documents, but even removing the client from my PC (just in case it was creating a locked file within the folder) has not worked.